# How to shuffle colour balls?

Tags: c#, combinations

I have 400 balls, in which 100 are red, 40 are yellow, 50 are green, 60 are blue, 70 are purple, 80 are black. (balls of the same colour are identical)

i need an efficient shuffling algorithm, so that after shuffling, balls are in a list, and

Any consecutive 3 balls are not of the same colour. e.g, i can not have "red, red, red, yellow...."

And, all permutation are "equally" likely to occur. (well, if the trade-off of efficiency vs. unbiasedness is good enough, i don't mind more efficiency than unbiasedness).

i tried to adapt Fisher-Yates-Knuth, but the outcome is not ideal.

Why Fisher-Yates not good enough? As FY adopts Monte Carlo inverse transformation. And the output distribution treats the same colour balls differently, i.e. it would generate biased result for my needs.

And, the Naive thinking would be to filter out / backtracking all bad permutations from the whole space. When the restriction is very strong, say, if we have only 300 balls and 100 of which are red, then there will be too many back tracking/failures before getting an appropriate permutation.

So, ultimately, I would wish to be able to iterate through all good permutations. However, because  the number of valid permutations is too large, i can only randomly sample some of them.

Comment: How did you try to adapt Fisher-Yates-Knuth and how is the outcome not "ideal"?

Comment: I think with a naïve solution you will end up with backtracking to ensure that your rule holds. Imagine if you have three balls left to pick and all three are the same colour; then you could, with a simple linear algorithm, not guarantee that no three consecutive ones are of one colour.

Comment: @joey: I tried using backtracking before, however, when the restriction is too strong for the input, the algorithm would take a lot of time backtracking, i.e. massive failures and retries

Comment: @colinfang Clarification question: are you trying to actually generate a SPECIFIC "shuffle" of 400 items (which happens to match the no-three-in-a-row constraint), OR are you trying to come up with random combinations of three-balls where the probability of the particular combination is the SAME as "picking a random three in a row as if they were from a valid [actual] shuffle".

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, FYK algoritm is swapinng random positions in array. Why can't you just produce the colors as I am decribing it in the pseudo code?

```
public IEnumerable<Color> GetColors()
{
   int count = 400;
   // queue or another data structure to hold the last generated colors
   Queue<Color> lastColors = new Queue<Color>(); 
   var availableColor = new Dictionary<Color, int> { 
     {Red, 100}, {Yellow, 40}, ...
   };
   Color nextColor = null;
   while(count > 0)
   {
     do {
       /* randomly pick from color buckets */
       nextColor = /* choose random color based on the weights*/;
     } while(/*it satisfies the condition, that it is not 3rd same color in a row*/)
     yield return nextColor;
     count--;
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you reach the end of the run with only 3 red balls left?

Comment: I don't know - it is hidden in "choose random color based on the weights"... The success of the algorithm depends on the input values, with 100xR and 1xG you won't get correct result.

Comment: ur algorithm is some variations of classic FY algorithm or monte carlo inverse transformation. It will not be efficient if the restriction for the input is too strong, which would result in too many failures, also the output is too biased.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking aloud, I'd try

- 'design' (think of) a (recursive) generator of valid combinations; make sure it generates the combinations in deterministic order;
- translate the generator to a deterministic numbering scheme (a magical number that uniquely identifies any one of your valid combinations)<sup>2</sup>
- implement the generator algorithm taking the target magic number as an argument, so that you don't have to do all the work to get to the *'n-th valid combination'*, but instead can 'jump' to the desired combination (this requires your recursive generation function to be *explicit* and *deterministic*; any backtracking would make this impossible).

Now, you could simply generate a uniformly distributed random 'magic' number between [0..max_number_of_valid_combinations]<sup>1</sup>. For each selected magic number, you can print the generated valid combination.

If you are interested, I might find some time to try my hand at this. (I'd prefer doing so in C++/Python, but C# should be possible (does .Net 4.0 ship the BigInteger calss yet?))

---

<sup>1</sup> (that could be a humongous number, so you could be stuck with BigInteger of some kind, and generating multiple random numbers to arrive at the large numbers. Make sure you understand the distribution algorithm to ensure this is really still uniformly distributed...

<sup>2</sup> there is a substantial amount of combinatorics to arrive at the proper multipliers to find the number of possible 'tail combinations' at a particular point during generation. This is the complexity bottleneck IMO

Comment: Yes, [BigInteger is in .Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) available.

Comment: max_number_of_valid_combinations would be too large. I would prefer to embed the rng into the generator. And to gain efficiency I wouldn't mind lose a some unbiasness. Afterall, i would like 10,000 unique permutations from the total spaces. On top of that, c++ is OK for me

Comment: @colinfang: too large for what? It only needs to be calculable, not enumerable